# Asymptotic behavior of $a_{n+1}=a_n + f(a_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, dynamical-systems

Let $f$ be $C^1([0,1])$ function. I'm looking for a good reference for the asymptotic behavior of $$a_{n+1}=a_n + f(a_n)$$ and it's relation to dynamical systems.

Comment: It doesn't seem apparent to me that you even can iterate this in general. When you add $a_n$ and $f(a_n)$ you may very well leave $[0,1]$.

Comment: Very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176858/asymptotic-behavior-of-iterative-sequences?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

As a first cut, I would write
$a_{n+1}-a_n \approx a'(x)$
so my guess would be
$a'(x) \approx f(a(x))$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, if $a_n \to L$, then $f(L)=0$.

Convergence will be guaranteed if $g:x \mapsto x+f(x)$ is a contraction, as long as $g([0,1]) \subseteq [0,1]$:

- $|g'(x)|<1$ iff $-2 < f(x) < 0$.
- $g([0,1]) \subseteq [0,1]$ iff $-x \le f(x) \le 1-x$.